# Syntax error when creating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python.  I just typed this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

states = [
    'Kerala': 'KL' ,
    'Tamil Nadu': 'TN',
    'Karnataka': 'KN',
    'Maharashtra': 'MH',
    'Delhi': 'DL'
]
```

I'm getting a syntax error

```
$ python ex39.py
    File "ex39.py", line 4
'Kerala': 'KL' ,
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I wonder what book or tutorial is using this *widely inaccurate* syntax. That's the second such a question (with the same mapping contents) I've seen so far.

Comment: The book is Learn python the Hard Way, I came across the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace '[' and ']' by '{' and '}'
[] are for lists, {} for dict.

Answer (score 0):

Python [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are delimited with `{` and `}`, not square brackets (which are for [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)):

```
states = {
  'Kerala': 'KL' ,
  'Tamil Nadu': 'TN',
  'Karnataka': 'KN',
  'Maharashtra': 'MH',
  'Delhi': 'DL'
}
```

Also, your title is not very descriptive. Perhaps change to something like "Syntax error when creating a dictionary"?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary should be declared like

```
mydict = {'key' : 'value' }
```

and not

```
mydict = [ 'key' : 'value' ]
```